# Moving a window that I cannot see

Tags: unity

I am running Natty Narwhal on x86_64 with the new "Unity" desktop.

I have two monitors.  Well, make that one monitor and a high-def television set.  I usually leave the TV off, or if it is on, it is usually set to display an input other than my Ubuntu system.

Sometimes, when an application decides to open a window, it opens it on the secondary display (i.e., the TV).  In earlier versions of Ubuntu (using gnome-desktop), I could right-click on the application in the task bar, select the name of the window, choose "Move", and drag it onto my primary display (i.e., the monitor).

With Natty, I have to turn on my television, wait for it to power up, set it to "HDMI input #3" (or whatever), mouse over to the TV, grab the window, drag it back, restore my TV to its default input, and turn it off.

I find this new process significantly less efficient than the old one.

Is there any way under Unity to move a window that I cannot see from one screen to another?  If not, how can I request this feature?

Thanks.

Comment: `how can I request this feature?` `superkey(win key)` + `w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***CompizConfig Settings Manager "Put"*** Option can help you to move the hidden window with a user definable key binding.

[image]

In my case, I use [Super] with a combination with the numeric keyboard, this way, when a window is far from the sight, or hidden below a full screen window, I can simply send it to another place in order to get the focus. Of course, I should use [Alt][Tab] or [Super][Tab] to choose the window that I wish to move.

Give this a try and let us know how did you do with this suggestion.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I will give it a try tonight.

Comment: Excellent; thank you.  Although...  Shouldn't this settings manager be part of the default install :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

To see hidden windows in Ubuntu 16.04, use the "Spreads all windows" (Super+,) or "Spreads all windows of the focused application" (Super+Ctrl+,) keyboard shortcuts. You can see what shortcuts are available by holding down the Super key.